# Does $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(M/N)$ imply the same minimal polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $L/K$ and $M/N$ be finite galois extension and $M\supseteq L, N\supseteq K$.

$\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(M/N)$ and write $L＝K(α)$.

Then, why $α$'s minimal polynomial over $K$ is also minimal polynomial over $N$ ?

I'm having trouble how to use condition $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K) \cong \operatorname{Gal}(M/N)$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might be able to get this if $L\cap N=K.$ Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true: take $K:=\mathbb{Q}$, $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $N:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $M:=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Then $L/K$ and $M/N$ are Galois extensions because these are separable quadratic extensions with Galois groups $\text{Gal}(L/K) \cong \text{Gal}(M/N) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$ is $X^2-2$ over $K$ and $X-\sqrt{2}$ over $N$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews no, because then $L \nsubseteq M$.

Comment: Ah, missed that - assumed the containments were the obvious ones. Should have read more carefully.